# Implementing a loop for each selected item in multi-listbox

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, loops, listbox

I am trying to implement a `foreach` loop for each selected item in a multi-listbox `UserProfileTrainingSearch`:

```
if (UserProfileTrainingSearch.SelectedValue != "-1" && //other conditions)
{
    foreach (var ListBoxItem in UserProfileTrainingSearch.SelectedValue) // only the first item selected is giving the results.
    {
        Session["UserbyTrainingType"] = "SELECT DISTINCT USERPROFILE.USER_ISN, USERPROFILE.LAST_NAME + ',' ..........................;
        SqlUserProfile.SelectCommand = (string)Session["UserbyTrainingType"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in UserProfileTrainingSearch.SelectedItems)
{
   // your code here
}
```